# Get current `--mode` in webpack.config.js

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-4

How can I get the current `--mode` specified in *package.json* inside *webpack.config.js*? (For instance, for pushing some plugins.)

```
package.json

"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

What I did in Webpack 3:

```
package.json

"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"
  },
```

Then, I was able to get environment in Webpack with `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Of course, I can pass `NODE_ENV` with `--mode` but I prefer to avoid duplication.

Comment: same question as you asked.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You want to avoid duplication of options passed on the script.

When you export a function, the function will be invoked with 2 arguments: an environment `env` as the first parameter **and an options map `argv` as the second parameter.**

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "build-dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build-prod": "webpack --mode production"
},
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    console.log(`This is the Webpack 4 'mode': ${argv.mode}`);
    return {
        ...
    };
}
```

These are the results:

For `npm run build-dev`:

```
> webpack --mode development

This is the Webpack 4 'mode': development
Hash: 554dd20dff08600ad09b
Version: webpack 4.1.1
Time: 42ms
Built at: 2018-3-14 11:27:35
```

For `npm run build-prod`:

```
> webpack --mode production

This is the Webpack 4 'mode': production
Hash: 8cc6c4e6b736eaa4183e
Version: webpack 4.1.1
Time: 42ms
Built at: 2018-3-14 11:28:32
```

Comment: This works, however, when I have to use `import/resolver` with eslint, it doesn't appear to accept a function.

Comment: for me, it worked by using "env.mode". the first parameter, and not the second.

Comment: @corvid Please check my answer, may be help you with the webpack resolver.

Comment: On Webpack's official documentation they use `argv.mode` to get the actual mode : https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

Comment: I up voted your answer because i was setting it with an equal `mode=production` instead of a space.... thanks

Answer (score 15):

To test if is in production mode, inside `webpack.config.js` file I use this:

```
const isProduction = process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('--mode') + 1] === 'production';

const config = {
    ...
};

if (isProduction) {
    config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());
} else { // isDev
    config.devtool = /*'source-map'*/  'inline-source-map';
}

module.exports = config;
```

Stop trying `NODE_ENV`, is old school ( *webpack 3* ).

And this is more compatible to work with  `import / webpack resolver`

Comment: It is disappointing that this is how Webpack expects us to get the mode. This is not at all clean.

Comment: You right... for things like that I leave it behind.

Comment: And then there is the alternative cli form of --mode=production. smh

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production --env.production"
}
```

so if you are using the `env` inside `webpack config`, that looks something like this

```
module.exports = env => {
     const inProduction = env.production
     return  {
        entry: {...},
        output: {...},
        module: {...}
     }
}
```

more details to set up your `webpack.config.js`. ([Environment Variables for webpack 4](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/))

Answer (score 1):

I ended up (ab)using `npm_lifecycle_script` to set the mode in the `DefinePlugin`:

```
MODE: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_lifecycle_script.substr(process.env.npm_lifecycle_script.indexOf('--mode ') + '--mode '.length, process.env.npm_lifecycle_script.substr(process.env.npm_lifecycle_script.indexOf('--mode ') + '--mode '.length).search(/($|\s)/)))
```

This takes the value of the `--mode` parameter from the issued `webpack` command.

Comment: Yes, I also use  `process.env.npm_lifecycle_script` to define `--production`, `--development` and `--watch` in the webpack command in npm to add different things to webpack configuration depending on it (babel loader only for production and browser sync plugin only for the start script with watch), but I really don't know whether it's a good practice.