# Vue 2.7 + webpack: all variables inside debugger are undefined / null

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

We have a Vue 2.7 SPA at my workplace.

Nobody ever configured a dev build for it, nobody ever used a debugger (it's a docker-compose environment).

I'm currently implementing the dev build, and so far it's been a success, except for the fact that I cannot access variables inside a debugger.

Source maps seem to work, since I can successfully place breakpoints inside `.vue` component files.

I start the dev server by:

```
npm run start -- --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

(it's inside a `docker-compose` network, so don't mind the `0.0.0.0` bit)

The `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --history-api-fallback",
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "webpack": "webpack --mode=development --watch"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 0.25%, not dead"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "inputmask-core": "^2.2.0",
        "mini-toastr": "^0.8.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.2",
        "qs": "^6.11.0",
        "v-mask": "^2.3.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.27.2",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
        "vue-notifications": "^0.9.0",
        "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^3.11.0",
        "vuetable-2": "^1.7.5",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
        "@prerenderer/renderer-jsdom": "^0.2.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
        "core-js": "^3.25.3",
        "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
        "del-cli": "^3.0.1",
        "eslint": "^8.25.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
        "prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.4.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "svg-sprite-loader": "^6.0.11",
        "svgo-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack": "^4.46.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-fix-style-only-entries": "^0.5.1"
    }
}
```

Finally, the `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require("webpack-fix-style-only-entries")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        allowedHosts: ["all"],
        disableHostCheck: true,
    },
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        css: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader', // <style lang="css">
                        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader', // <style lang="scss">
                        sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax' // <style lang="sass">
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/icons'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                        options: {
                            extract: true,
                            publicPath: '/assets/icons/',
                            spriteFilename: svgPath => `sprite${svgPath.substr(-4)}`
                        }
                    },
                    // 'svg-sprite-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'svgo-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                {
                                    name: 'removeAttributesBySelector',
                                    params: {
                                        selector: "[stroke='#787F9B']",
                                        attributes: "stroke"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'removeAttributesBySelector',
                                    params: {
                                        selector: "[fill='#787F9B']",
                                        attributes: "fill"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'removeAttributesBySelector',
                                    params: {
                                        selector: "[stroke='#B2BAD8']",
                                        attributes: 'stroke'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'removeAttributesBySelector',
                                    params: {
                                        selector: "[fill='#B2BAD8']",
                                        attributes: 'fill'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'removeAttributesBySelector',
                                    params: {
                                        selector: "[fill='none']",
                                        attributes: "fill"
                                    }
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                {
                                    "debug": true,
                                    "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                                    "corejs": "3.22"
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'assets/img/[name].[ext]',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            additionalData: "@import '@/assets/scss/colors.scss';"
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/](node_modules)[\\/].+\.js$/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                }
            }
        },
        minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: { map: { inline: false, }, },
                cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                    preset: [
                        'default',
                        { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
                    ],
                },
            }),
            new TerserPlugin({
                extractComments: false,
                terserOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            layouts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/layouts'),
            utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
            routes: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes'),
            assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
            vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.min.js'
            // 'vue-resource': 'vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.esm.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.png']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'API_URL': `'${process.env.API_URL || ""}'`,
            'WS_URL': `'${process.env.WS_URL || ""}'`,
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: './src/robots.txt', to: './assets/robots.txt' },
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/img/favicon.ico'),
            ],
        }),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        new SpriteLoaderPlugin({
            plainSprite: true,
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './assets/css/[name].[hash].bundle.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            // MANIFEST_FILENAME: '/assets/manifest.json',
            template: 'src/index.html',
            title: '...',
            favicon: 'src/assets/img/favicon.ico',
            // inject: false,
            // scripts: [`/app.js?v=${new Date().getTime()}`]
            meta: [{
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
            }]
            // links: [
            //     "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css",
            //     {rel: "shortcut icon", href: "/assets/icons/favicon.ico", type: "image/x-icon"},
            // ]
        }),
    ],
};
```

It's the last frontier of the dev environment, which I haven't yet been able to conquer.

I understand the problem: arguments / variables get mangled during the minification process. Here is component's method, which I was trying to debug:

```
async onAddUsdtTrc20Wallet() {
      try {
        const response = await this.createNewCryptoWallet('USDT-TRC20X');
        const address = response.wallet_address;
        this.showSuccess(this.$t('profilePage.wallets.successAddUsdtTrc20Wallet') + address);
      } catch (err) {
        this.showError(this.$t('profilePage.wallets.errorAddUsdtTrc20Wallet') + err.toString());
      }
    }
```

After minification it looks like this:

```
    onAddUsdtTrc20Wallet: function onAddUsdtTrc20Wallet() {
      var _this7 = this;
      return _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/_regeneratorRuntime().mark(function _callee2() {
        var response, address;
        return _regeneratorRuntime().wrap(function _callee2$(_context2) {
          while (1) {
            switch (_context2.prev = _context2.next) {
              case 0:
                _context2.prev = 0;
                _context2.next = 3;
                return _this7.createNewCryptoWallet('USDT-TRC20X');
              case 3:
                response = _context2.sent;
                address = response.wallet_address;
                _this7.showSuccess(_this7.$t('profilePage.wallets.successAddUsdtTrc20Wallet') + address);
                _context2.next = 11;
                break;
              case 8:
                _context2.prev = 8;
                _context2.t0 = _context2["catch"](0);
                _this7.showError(_this7.$t('profilePage.wallets.errorAddUsdtTrc20Wallet') + _context2.t0.toString());
              case 11:
              case "end":
                return _context2.stop();
            }
          }
        }, _callee2, null, [[0, 8]]);
      }))();
    }
```

What I tried:

- I tried using `"devtool": "eval-source-map"`.
- Tried removing `"minimizer"` and setting `"minify"` field inside `"optimization"` to `false`.
- Tried setting `TerserPlugin` options to `{minify: TerserPlugin.esbuildMinify, terserOptions: { minify: false, minifyWhitespace: true, minifyIdentifiers: false, minifySyntax: true,}`
- Tried removing `optimization` altogether.

None of these steps changed the generated `app.js` output script. Double checked by `exec -it`ing inside the container to make sure new `webpack.config.js` was in place.

Anybody had this kind of problem?

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem exactly. Which variables do you debug and in which way? You can try to set terserOptions.mangle to false, but they don't look minified, and this obviously won't make all variable names the same because some have to be different due to the way code is transpiled

Comment: @EstusFlask all I'm trying to do is to debug the code inside a chrome / firefox debugger. If I place the breakpoint on the `this.showError` line, when it's hit I cannot access `err`, as it is undefined. Same goes for `this` (which becomes `_this7`), etc.

Comment: @EstusFlask The source maps seem to be in place, since I can hit the breakpoint correctly and reliably. When I developed for vue3, I could always access the variables from any browser's debugger.

Comment: It's not directly related to Vue version. This totally depends on what the variables are. In this case they are certainly affected by transpilation transforms that are needed for your ES target and not by a minifier. Source map makes you able to hover on a variable in a debugger at a breakpoint and show it's value like https://coderpad.io/blog/development/javascript-debugging-in-chrome , it physically cannot affect how things appear in a console and create references for vars that don't exist in this scope.

Comment: The relevant part isn't shown, which is babel config. It affects ES target, currently it appears to be ES5, needs to be higher to get rid of most side effects, at least ES2017. You can have a different ES target for dev mode but then there can be transpilation-related surprises when things stop working the way they should in prod. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712662/react-this-is-undefined-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: @EstusFlask ok, I got you, sorry, that I didn't provide the relevant part, as I wasn't sure what the relevant part was. I will look into it more carefully and update the question accordingly in hopes you'd be willing to further help me out.

Comment: No problem, it could be that you showed all you have, in case there are no specific babel config files. Then the output likely depends only on with "> 0.25%, not dead", or babel/preset-env defaults. Could be something like `targets: argv.mode==production ? "> 0.25%, not dead" : "last 2 chrome version"` in `@babel/preset-env` config. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274713/get-current-mode-in-webpack-config-js and https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-env#targets to make it more debugger-friendly in dev mode. Otherwise see the topic on debugging transformed code, that's the way in prod